# Subprocess Popen invalid argument/broken pipe while communicating to C program

Tags: python, arrays, pipe, subprocess

I have this code

All the needed libraries are imported

```
class VERTEX(Structure):
 _fields_ = [("index", c_int),
            ("x", c_float),
            ("y", c_float)]
```

Other stuff

This create and array from a list of vertex

```
def writelist_buf(size, nomeID): 
 Nvert_VERTEX_Array_Type = VERTEX * len(bpy.data.objects[nomeID].data.vertices)
 passarr = Nvert_VERTEX_Array_Type()
 for i in range(len(passarr)):
  vert = bpy.data.objects[nomeID].data.vertices[i]
  passarr[i] = VERTEX(vert.index, vert.co[0], vert.co[1])
 return passarr
```

bpy.data.objects[nomeID].data.vertices is a list of vertices.

Other stuff

This is inside a def, and communicate to a C program the previous array

```
input = writelist_buf(size, nomeID)
c_program_and_args = "here is the program with his arguments(it works)"
cproc = Popen(c_program_and_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = cproc.communicate(input)
#the program returns 2 integers separed by a space
return [int(i) for i in out.decode.split()]
```

size and nomeID are declared before the writelist call.

After a bit of "debugging" i found that the type passed by the writelist_buf is "legal"(it's bytes, since is an array created with c_types), but i keep receiving a Errno32 Broken Pipe or Errno22 Invalid argument... The C program just make a read in the stdiin to retrive all the vertices(like the C code below)..

The strange think is that before "integrating" inside the code i was working on, i have tried a simpler code: this one, and it works!

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from ctypes import *

class VERTEX(Structure):
 _fields_ = [("index", c_int),
            ("x", c_float),
            ("y", c_float)]

nverts = 5
vlist = [VERTEX(0,1,1), VERTEX(1,2,2), VERTEX(2,3,3), VERTEX(3,4,4), VERTEX(4,5,5)]
array = VERTEX * nverts
input = array()
for i in range(nverts):
 input[i] = vlist[i]
print(type(input))
cproc = Popen("pipeinout.exe random arg", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = cproc.communicate(input)
print(out.decode())
```

And the C code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    int index;
    float x;
    float y;
} vertex;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n=5;
    int i;
    printf("%s",argv[1]);
    vertex* VV;
    VV=(vertex*)malloc(sizeof(vertex)*n);
    fread(VV,sizeof(vertex),n,stdin);
    //fread(&VV,sizeof(VV),1,stdin);//metti nel valore di VV(non a quello che punta) l'indirizzo passato||sizeof(VV) is the size of a pointer
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf(" %i , %f , %f\n",VV[i].index,VV[i].x,VV[i].y);
}
```

Comment: are you really using only one space for indentation, or is it a copy mistake?

Comment: @utdmr it's only a copy mistake. Usually i use tabs, and sometimes spaces because a program in which i use python scripts reads tabs as 4 spaces, but usually i wrote it with tabs and then replace them :)

Comment: Replace `out.decode.split()` by `out.split()`. `input` must be string or buffer; replace `.communicate(input)` by `.communicate(buffer(input))`. Don't use wildcard import.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : didn't know this was a wrong thing.
Buffer is not defined. I'm using 3.1. I saw this was a comand of the 2.7, but didn't found it in 3.1 docs

Comment: use `memoryview()` on Python3. btw, you should mention it in your question and use `python-3.x` tag.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian ` input=writelist_buf(size, nomeID) c_program_and_args = "some as before" cproc = Popen(c_program_and_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) out, err = cproc.communicate(memoryview(input)) ret= out.split() ` But it gives broken pipe..

Comment: it *might* be a problem with padding and memory alignment among members of the structure and/or items of the array. The following works on my machine https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian The last python code and C code works too in my machine, the problem is that making the same thing in the other script it gives errors.. Can it be because in my script i pass much more data(the array is of 65000 elements)?

Comment: @Makers_F: I've tried for 100000 vertices https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1 (it starts to print zeros after 98815).

Comment: @Makers_F: this produces correct output (but it doesn't use .communicate()) https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/9814b9f60333a018984ef49301f241f5bcd6848d This prints incorrect output after 98815 https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/ed81d2650a90eef6dcdd3f60dd6416b54b7fc79b

Comment: @Makers_F: IIRC you previously indicated that in its final form, this program will call the c subprocess 500 times in rapid succession. I take it the version that works does not do that? And I'm guessing the broken version tries to do that?

Comment: Here's version that uses `struct` module https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/2a144f15bb08fe3b3def35040a16402e7aaa6848

Comment: yes, the working version call it one time. The broken one calls it a first time to determinate the max and min vertices, and then start calling many times. By now it crashes at the first call(so i don't think the problem is calling it many times). It keeps giving error writing to the stdin.
A little note: i'm testing it on 70000c.a. vertices, but it need to work on more than a million. Passing data with binary files(and this is low) works with more than 5 millions, so i was hoping to find a way that works with that many vertices :)

Comment: @j.F Sebastian If you want to see all the code, https://gist.github.com/824069
But is full of things that doesn't matter with the problem.
(in my code you'll see i use pack, but is so slow..)

Comment: @Makers_F: On my machine the struct version https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/d8d0c6e4917f40df4bceb43feb681a17a1cabe6c is 1.5 times faster for n=6000000 than (VERTEX*n) array version https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/5df1ddd79a67a66c0261c96b2fffd0ab1be0ad8c (I've tried both implicitly converting to VERTEX on the array initialization and explicitly creating vertices as VERTEX from the beginning. Both variants are slower than the struct.Struct one).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian i know it can be boring, but please, can you explain your code? I don't really get how it works, and i prefer not to use code i don't understand(if later i need to change things, i would not know how to manage these parts of code..)

Comment: @Makers_F: Sure. I'll post the code. You could ask in the comments about parts that require an explanation.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian you are so kind.
I don't really understand the pack functions (i know that yield returns an iterable object that is iterable only one time, but in your code you use 2 yield, so i don't get what it returns. In addition i dont know what (*v) means at line 10)
I don't get how the Thread in line 25 works, and all the read output of the program.. It isn't stored in a variable, is it? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I understand that you pass millions of items hundreds of times to a C program. The approach below (pipe input using subprocess) *might* be too slow in your case. Possible alternatives could be to write a C extension (e.g., using Cython) or to use `ctypes`  to call C functions directly. You could ask a separate question describing your use case in detail about what approach could be preferable.

If you've chosen an approach then make sure that it works correctly before any optimization (write some tests, measure performance and only after optimize it if needed) -- [*Make it work, make it right, make it fast*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast).

On the other hand there is no point to invest too much time in approaches that are known to be thrown away later -- *Fail fast*.

if the output of the C program is bounded; the `.communicate()` method from your code works ([source](https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/80748f64d762c4456a07671a4fed5668f8c68de6)):

```
import struct, sys    
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

vertex_struct = struct.Struct('i f f')

def pack(vertices, n):    
    yield struct.pack('i', n)
    for v in vertices:
        yield vertex_struct.pack(*v)

def main():
    try: n = int(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        n = 100
    vertices = ((i,i+1,i+2) for i in range(n))

    p = Popen(["./echo_vertices", "random", "arg"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    out, _ = p.communicate(b''.join(pack(vertices, n)))

    index, x, y = vertex_struct.unpack(out)
    assert index == (n-1) and int(x) == n and int(y) == (n+1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's [the code](https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/d8d0c6e4917f40df4bceb43feb681a17a1cabe6c) from the comments to the question. It works without errors for large `n` values on my machine:

```
import struct, sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

def pack(vertices, n):
    yield struct.pack('i', n)
    s = struct.Struct('i f f')
    for v in vertices:
        yield s.pack(*v)

def write(output_file, chunks):
    for chunk in chunks:
        output_file.write(chunk)
    output_file.close()

def main():
    try: n = int(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        n = 100
    vertices = ((i,i+1,i+2) for i in range(n))

    p = Popen(["./echo_vertices", "random", "arg"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

    Thread(target=write, args=[p.stdin, pack(vertices, n)]).start()

    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        pass
    p.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)
    p.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Q&A

> **Q:** I don't really understand the pack
>   functions (i know that yield returns
>   an iterable object that is iterable
>   only one time, but in your code you
>   use 2 yield, so i don't get what it
>   returns.

`pack()` is a generator. Generators do not work how you've described them, e.g.:

```
>>> def f():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
... 
>>> for i in f():
...     print(i)
...     
1
2
```

Note each `yield` produces a value.

```
>>> def g(n):
...     for i in range(n):
...         yield i
... 
>>> list(g(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Here's the `yield` is present in the text only one time but it is executed 10 times and each time it produces a value (an integer in this case). See [Generators](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/classes.html#generators) in the Python tutorial. ["Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers"](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) contains multiple examples on how to use generators from a simple to an advanced usage.

---

> **Q:** In addition i dont know what
>   (*v) means at line 10)

`s.pack(*v)` calls the `pack` method using [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> def h(a, b):
...     print(a, b)
... 
>>> h(*[1, 'a'])
1 a
>>> h(*range(2))
0 1
>>> h(0, 1)
0 1
```

---

> **Q:** I don't get how
>   the Thread in line 25 works,

```
Thread(target=write, args=[p.stdin, pack(vertices, n)]).start()
```

This line starts a new thread that calls `write()` function with the arguments from the `args` keyword argument i.e. `output_file=p.stdin` and `chunks=pack(vertices, n)`. The `write()` function in this case is equivalent to:

```
p.stdin.write(struct.pack('i', n))
p.stdin.write(s.pack(0, 1, 2))
p.stdin.write(s.pack(1, 2, 3))
...
p.stdin.write(s.pack(n-1, n, n+1))
p.stdin.close()
```

After that the thread exits.

---

> **Q:** ...and all
>   the read output of the program.. It
>   isn't stored in a variable, is it?

The whole output is not stored anywhere. The code:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    pass
```

reads from `p.stdout` line-by-line until the `.readline()` returns empty string `b''` and stores the current line in the `line` variable (see [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#iter) docs). So:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)
```

just prints the last line of the output.

---

> **Q:** 1)after starting the Thread, the
>   python script waits until it finished,
>   right?

No, the main thread exits. The started thread is not daemon. It runs until it completes i.e., the script (the program) doesn't exit until it completes.

---

> **Q:** 2)i understood how you read
>   from the stdout of the C program,but i
>   don't get when you start it.Afa i
>   understood,with the write function we
>   write in a buffer(or something like a
>   file in the ram) the data we want,and
>   when we run the c program, it can read
>   from it the data we wrote.But when we
>   start the C program in your code? :)

The C program is started by `p = Popen(...)`.

`p.stdin.write()` writes to `stdin` of the C program (there are number of buffers in between but we can forget about it for a moment). The process is the same as in:

```
$ echo abc | some_program
```

---

> **Q:** 3)last thing: why do you use a wait on
>   p? There's a warning
>   http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?#subprocess.Popen.wait

For the provided C code it is not necessary to write to `p.stdin` in a separate thread. I use the thread exactly to avoid the situation described in the warning i.e., C program produces enough output before the script finishes writing to its stdin (your C code doesn't write anything before it finishes reading so the thread is not necessary).

In other words `p.wait()` is safe in this case.

Without `p.wait()` stderr output from the C program might be lost. Though I can reproduce the stderr loss only on jython with [the scripts](https://gist.github.com/7c1921a7bca7094136f7). Yet again for the provided C code it doesn't matter due to it is not writing to stderr anything.

Comment: I don't really understand the pack(vertices, n) function (i know that yield returns an iterable object that is iterable only one time, but in your code you use 2 yield, so i don't get what it returns. In addition i dont know what (*v) means at line 10) I don't get how the Thread in line 25 works, and all the read output of the program.. It isn't stored in a variable, is it? Thank you so much!!
Last thing: you never call the write(output_file, chunks) function..

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Your explanations were really clear!Just the last questions:1)after starting the Thread,the python script waits until it finished,right?2)i understood how you read from the stdout of the C program,but i don't get when you start it.Afa i understood,with the write function we write in a buffer(or something like a file in the ram) the data we want,and when we run the c program,it can read from it the data we wrote.But when we start the C program in your code?:) 3)last thing:why do you use a wait on p? There's a warning docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?#subprocess.Popen.wait

Comment: @Makers_F: I've added some comments at the top of the answer (regarding general problem) and answered the questions from your last comment at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: you have quite wrote a whole book on python ;) Thank you so much for the effort. Yes, maybe this may be a bit slow. The problems are 2: 1) since at start for passing the data i used files i had 2 problems: they were slow and i need to handle the right path for them 2) i need to find a os independent solution(i'll distribute che code)
By now, i didn't realized yet the best solution, but pipes at start looked fast and portable, but with big numbers they fail.. Thank you so much for the help, i'll open a new question for creating a shareed library to load with ctypes :)

Comment: @Makers_F: I said it *might* be slow. I don't know whether it is the case. The code I provided works for at least `n=1e8`. I don't know how `fread()` works hence my comment about portability. The code could very well work as is on various OSes (test it). The error you see could be a bug in your code. You can use pipes to pass at least GBytes of data.

Comment: If pipes haven't a small limit, then they should fit. By now they are one of the best solution, and i feel we are about to make it!
I think the remaining problems are 2:1) the write function should write in the stdin only one time all the data. Even if not memory efficiently, this can be done substituting the output_file in the write function with a buffer object or an ctypes array, and then writing the array/buffer at once(don't know what is best) 2) don't calling the program in another thread, but using subprocess.call(or better check_call) so that the script waits for the output

Comment: @Makers_F: The first rule of optimization: *don't do it*. Do not introduce micro-optimizations unless your profiler says you so. NOTE: The thread does not call any programs; it just pumps data into the pipe. You could use `.communicate()` as in your original code if `echo_vertices` doesn't produce gigantic output  https://gist.github.com/6b46c1237cca16ef30c1/5d3a979eca066af9b0bae2083fe368bd250970eb

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Ok, your code seams to be exactly what i need. I assume that b''.join(pack(vertices, n)) create something like an array of vertices. Maybe i didn't understand one thin about popen. When you call this function, the program is actually run? If so, isn't there the possibility that the program is executed before your code write in the stdin? Or the program is run when you use .communicate()? I just have this doubt.. Here the code https://gist.github.com/824069 (i've simplified it a lot). Why should avoid using communicate for large output? stdout.read would be fine?

Comment: @Makers_F: `b''.join()` creates `bytes` object (run `help(bytes)`). The program blocks on `fread()` until it receives input (you can put `time.sleep(120)` between `Popen()` and `.communicate()` and see that the C program is running in the task manager). You could use `.communicate()` for a gigantic output until you run out of memory. btw, replace `out.decode` by `out.decode()`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Perfect. (the code i posted is has several errors, but i corrected them while trying to run it) I managed to pass the data to the C program and to retrieve the output, sometimes it gave the right result, but sometimes something went wrong, it gave wrong results or stopped before it actually have should.. Don't know if is some error in the script or in the C program, i can figure out what can be wrong..

Comment: +1 -- @J.F. Sebastian, you put an amazing amount of work into this answer. You deserve at least a couple more votes; too bad I can't give them to you.

Comment: @Makers_F: Write small example that reproduces your error. Try to *understand* your code by reading it and check every assumption you've made e.g., if some parameter should always be 1 or 2 then make an explicit check in the code that it is so. Add unit tests (test every function in isolation) http://diveintopython3.org/unit-testing.html

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Interesting reading, but i really don't know how to predict the output, since the indices of the vertex are given something like random(otherwise i wouldn't need the program to retrieve them). Btw the program doesn't work any more, i don't think i changed anything.. Here the incriminated code (error_code.py) https://gist.github.com/824069 it gives error 22 Invalid argument, but the argument are bytes, so i don't know what can be wrong. I've tryed to print it, and it actually was a long bytes string..

Comment: @Makers_F: use `assert isinstance(the_thing, bytes)` to check that `the_thing` is a `bytes` object. Don't use wildcard import.

Comment: @Makers_F: At some point the vertexes are in your code. Save them to disk in some form. Write a test that reads them from disk and executes relevant parts of your code. Thus you can reproduce your error reliably. Read the test. Make sure you understand every line. Write more tests that check your understanding (if you think something should be `bytes`, don't guess make an *explicit* check). I don't see any guards in your code e.g., you should always check what `malloc()` returns. Check that `func`, `vnumber`, `sqsize` have expected values, etc.