# A way to pass milions of items in python to C program many times in rapid succesion

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes, extend

I've wrote a python script that need to pass millions of items to a C program and receive its output many times in a short period (pass from 1 up to 10 millions of vertices data (integer index and 2 float coords) rapidly 500 times, and each time the python script call the C program, i need to store the returned values in variables). I already implemented a way reading and writing text and or binary files, but it's slow and not smart(why write files to hdd while you don't need to store the data after the python script terminates?). I tried to use pipes, but for large data they gave me errors...
So, by now i think the best way can be using the ability of ctypes to load functions in .dll
Since i've never created a dll, i would like to know how to set it up (i know many ide have a template for this, but my wxdev-c++ crashes when i try to open it. Right now i'm downloading Code::Blocks )

Can you tell me if the solution i'm starting to implement is right, or if there is a better solution?
The 2 functions i need to call in python are these

```
void find_vertex(vertex *list, int len, vertex* lower, vertex* highter)
{
    int i;
    *lower=list[0];
    *highter=list[1];
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if ((list[i].x<=lower->x) && (list[i].y<=lower->y))
            *lower=list[i];
        else
        {
            if ((list[i].x>=highter->x) && (list[i].y>=highter->y))
                *highter=list[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
vertex *square_list_of_vertex(vertex *list,int len,vertex start, float size)
{
    int i=0,a=0;
    unsigned int *num;
    num=(int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*len);
    if (num==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't allocate the memory");
        return 0;
    }
    //controlls which points are in the right position and adds their index from the main list in another list
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if ((list[i].x-start.x)<size && (list[i].y-start.y<size))
        {
            if (list[i].y-start.y>-size/100)
            {
                num[a]=i;
                a++;//len of the list to return
            }
        }
    }

    //create the list with the right vertices
    vertex *retlist;
    retlist=(vertex*)malloc(sizeof(vertex)*(a+1));
    if (retlist==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't allocate the memory");
        return 0;
    }
    //the first index is used only as an info container
    vertex infos;
    infos.index=a+1;
    retlist[0]=infos;

    //set the value for the return pointer
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        retlist[i]=list[num[i-1]];
    }

    return retlist;
}
```

EDIT:
forgot to post the type defintion of vertex

```
typedef struct{
    int index;
    float x,y;
} vertex;
```

EDIT2:
I'll redistribute the code, so i prefer not to use external modules in python and external programs in C. Alsa i want try to keep the code cross platform. The script is an addon for a 3D app, so the less it uses external "stuff" the better it is.

Comment: "for large data they gave me errors"?  Please be specific.  What errors?  Pipes can handle an large volume of data, limited only by OS memory.

Comment: Even assuming only 1 million items per vertix and optimal memory layout, you'd need about 5.6 GB (not GiB) if Google's calculator doesn't betray me. You propably *can't* store this RAM unless you have some supercomputer at your command.

Comment: @delnan: 1 million vertices is only 16 MB in C, and 104 MB in Python.

Comment: @S. Lott http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979421/subprocess-popen-invalid-argument-broken-pipe-while-comunicating-to-c-program/4987203#4987203 Keeps giving error 32 pipe broken
@delnan 1'188'100 vertices saved in a binary file are 13,5 MB (14.257.200 byte)(it's just a struct.Struct('iff') for each vertex). So maybe the google calculator failed ;)
(i read the size of the file after saving them to file with a script and looking at the properties of the file)

Comment: @Rosh @OP: Aren't you having 500 of those? Calculator would about agree with this (11 MB).

Comment: int = 4, float = 8, so 20 bytes per struct. Then 20*one million=20 million byte that divided by 2^20 are around 15 MB

Comment: The C data type `float` has only 4 bytes.  The Python type `float` corresponds to the C type `double` and has 8 bytes.

Comment: "Keeps giving error 32 pipe broken"?  Why aren't you debugging that?  Why are you asking this question when you have code that has a simple error?

Comment: S.Lott The python script is executed inside another program, and it uses an api of that program that uses data of objects in that program. It isn't run inside another process, but inside the process of the program. I don't really know how to debug it(and i never debugged code) By now i solved the pipe problem, but since i'm still learning, i would like to learn even calling a shared library function, so i can do it in future if i need and i can give choices to who will use my script ;)

Comment: Don't print to `stdout` on errors if you use `stdout` to communicate with an external program that expects formatted input. You could use `perror("malloc");` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `ctypes` or Cython to wrap your C functions is definitely the way to go.  That way, you won't even need to copy the data between the C and Python code -- both the C and the Python part run within the same process and access the same data.  Let's stick with `ctypes`, since this is what you suggested.  Additionally, using NumPy will make this a lot more comfortable.

I infer your `vertex` type looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int index;
    float x, y;
} vertex;
```

To have these vertices in a NumPy array, you can define a record "dtype" for it:

```
vertex_dtype = [('index', 'i'), ('x', 'f'), ('y', 'f')]
```

Also define this type as a `ctypes` structure:

```
class Vertex(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("index", ctypes.c_int),
                ("x", ctypes.c_float),
                ("y", ctypes.c_float)]
```

Now, the `ctypes` prototype for your function `find_vertex()` would look like this:

```
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
lib = ctypes.CDLL(...)
lib.find_vertex.argtypes = [ndpointer(dtype=vertex_dtype, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                            ctypes.c_int,
                            ctypes.POINTER(Vertex),
                            ctypes.POINTER(Vertex)]
lib.find_vertex.restypes = None
```

To call this function, create a NumPy array of vertices

```
vertices = numpy.empty(1000, dtype=vertex_dtype)
```

and two structures for the return values

```
lower = Vertex()
higher = Vertex()
```

and finally call your function:

```
lib.find_vertex(vertices, len(vertices), lower, higher)
```

NumPy and `ctypes` will take care of passing the pointer to the beginning of the data of `vertices` to your C function -- no copying required.

Probably, you will have to read a bit of documentation on `ctypes` and NumPy, but I hope this answer helps you to get started with it.

Comment: Yes, i already used the cytpe structure while trying to use popen function.
Since with ctypes we can call functions, create arrays and pointes, why should i use NumPy(that is an external module and then need to be installed on every machine that wants to run the code)? If possible i prefer to use only standard modules..

Comment: @Makers_F: It *is* possible to do it without NumPy.  Handling and memory management of `ctypes` arrays is very error-prone though, and it is very hard to debug.  Furthermore, with NumPy you can efficiently do many things in Python which otherwise would have to be done in C.  Pretty much anyone handling large uniform arrays in Python uses NumPy, and I do consider it quite "standard".

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you really want is to turn your C program into a Python module. [Here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) is a tutorial that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data between two programs, and you already have the code to use a file, why not just use a RAMdisk? For Windows, you can use something like http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk to create the RAMdisk and you can use the commands listed [here](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2010/03/24/fastest-way-to-create-ramdisk-in-ubuntulinux/) for Linux. For smallish amounts of data (anything that will fit in RAM without requiring to be constantly paged out), this should outperform disk-based operations by a couple of orders of magnitude.

Comment: Yes, it was one of my first thoughts. I edited my first answer, look at it :)
In addition, in my case i don't need the 2 programs to "communicate", but more simply the python program have to call the C program passing him some data, and after it finished read the returned value. The os.system or subprocess.call would be the best thing if they only can handle big quantities of data..
I know in linux there are built in commands to create ramdisks, the problem then is windows, and i want not to use external programs..

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use a library like [sysv ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc) for this job and simply map the data to a shared memory segment.

Comment: Another thing i thought about. If there is a way to use it without external programs i can definitely go with this!

Comment: @Makers_F Yes , IPC means interprocess communication, it is designed for sharing data between processes.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over millions of items is the worst possible operation you could do in Python... If at all possible write this portion of the program in C or C++, it will be 100's of times faster and use 100's of times less memory...

I love python, but it's not a best solution for this type of operation.

Comment: Yeah, i'm totally with you, and if i only can i would. The problems are:
1) the script works as an addon of a program with a python api that interfaces with the C data of the program. I can get the address in memory stored by the program (it is written in C)of the data i want to use(the vertex), but even if i pass it to my C program i wouldn't be able to access it because of the memory space limitation. In addition, even if the program is open source, i don't know enough his structure to know how to handle the data, so i discarded this way..

Answer (score 0):

If you can, make the Python program buffer the data that it is sending so that it does not send every vertex one by one. Save them up until there are 100 or 500 or 1000 and that way you will make fewer calls. Do some timing tests to determine optimal buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant that uses Cython to write an extension module for CPython.

#### C declarations to be used in Cython:

```
# file: cvertex.pxd
cdef extern from "vertex.h":
    ctypedef struct vertex:
        int index
        float x,y
    void find_vertex(vertex *list, int len, vertex* lower, vertex* highter)
```

Where `vertex.h` is:

```
typedef struct{
    int index;
    float x,y;
} vertex;

void find_vertex(vertex *list, int len, vertex* lower, vertex* highter);
```

#### Cython implementation to be used in Python:

```
# file: pyvertex.pyx
cimport numpy
cimport cvertex # use declarations from cvertex.pxd

def find_vertex(numpy.ndarray[cvertex.vertex,ndim=1,mode="c"] vertices):
    if len(vertices) < 2:
        raise ValueError('provide at least 2 vertices')

    cdef cvertex.vertex lower, highter
    cvertex.find_vertex(<cvertex.vertex*>vertices.data, len(vertices),
                        &lower, &highter)
    return lower, highter # implicitly convert to dicts
```

#### To compile the extension, run:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext -i
```

Where `setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("vertex", ["pyvertex.pyx", "vertex.c"])]
)
```

#### Now the extension can be used from Python:

```
import numpy
import vertex # import the extension

n = 10000000
vertex_list = numpy.zeros(n, dtype=[('index', 'i'), ('x', 'f'), ('y', 'f')])
i = n//2
vertex_list[i] = i, 1, 1
v1, v2 = vertex.find_vertex(vertex_list)
print(v2['index'])
print(v1, v2)
```

Output

```
5000000
{'y': 0.0, 'index': 0, 'x': 0.0} {'y': 1.0, 'index': 5000000, 'x': 1.0}
```